# Blueprint android studio item to top right by default

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm currently trying to make a layout in android studio however, everytime I'm adding something to my component tree it stick to the top right corner of the blueprint. I can't put seem to attach to sides my object that I want to add in my visual

THIS IS WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKYR9.png)

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W43dN.png)

Comment: Share the code you will get better answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to Change the  layout from coordinate layout to constrain layout so that use can constrain at specific position,In Case You are Using Coordinate Layout Try "gravity"to align as Your Wish,
Extra:
Always try another layout inside constrain Layout..